# Tab auto completion does not work in gsettings and dconf?

Tags: dconf, gsettings

Earlier, when I used to do `gsettings get org.gnome.` <kbd>Tab</kbd> , a list of different options used to get listed. But then I changed some settings and updated my computer and found out today that <kbd>Tab</kbd> auto completion is not working in `gsettings` and `dconf` either.

How do I set <kbd>Tab</kbd> auto completion again ?

Although <kbd>Tab</kbd> auto completion is working fine in shell when I have to auto complete the name of a utility or name of a file.

I'm using `bash version 4.4.12(1)`

Output of `apt-cache policy bash-completion`

> ```
> bash-completion:
>    Installed: 1:2.1-4.3
>    Candidate: 1:2.1-4.3
>    Version table:
>   *** 1:2.1-4.3 500
>         500 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages
>         100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
> ```

Comment: Which shell are you using? If it is `bash`, Can you please check `bash-completion` package is available in your system?

Comment: Is your plan still to [reinstall](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62717/discussion-between-thushi-and-gypsycosmonaut)?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes, I would reinstall my OS sometime soon to see if this is resolved after that, why ? You're also facing the same problem ? I would update in the comments if it works after re-installation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `bash`, Since OP haven't mentioned which shell is being used!

In order to list out or auto complete the schema files from `XDG_DATA_DIR` your distro should have `bash-completion` package installed.
If it's not available please do install it using `apt-get install bash-completion` and restarting the terminal should work!

Comment: I checked and found out, this package was already installed. I'm using `Bash 4.4.12(1)`

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut: I am not talking about `bash` but `bash-completion`. Can you please paste the output of `apt-cache policy bash-completion` ?

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: Ok, It looks fine. So, still it doesn't work? if  you have installed it now. Please do restart the terminal!

Comment: Restarted, the `gnome-terminal`. Doesn't work.

Comment: are you sure your default shell is `bash`? Can you paste the output of `echo $SHELL`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62717/discussion-between-thushi-and-gypsycosmonaut).